# Send static but sometimes changing file

Tags: flask

I want to serve a few mostly static but sometimes changing files with flask. Right now they lie in the `static` directory and can be accessed on `/static/filename`, and sometimes a new version of the file is generated and written in the static directory by the flask app, but the problem is they don't get automatically updated in the browser unless I press the refresh button in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a version query string for you static resource.

a good example from [June](https://github.com/pythoncn/june/blob/master/june/app.py#L85):

```
def register_jinja(app):
    ...

    if not hasattr(app, '_static_hash'):
        app._static_hash = {}

    def static_url(filename):
        if app.testing:
            return filename

        if filename in app._static_hash:
            return app._static_hash[filename]

        with open(os.path.join(app.static_folder, filename), 'r') as f:
            content = f.read()
            hsh = hashlib.md5(content).hexdigest()

        app.logger.info('Generate %s md5sum: %s' % (filename, hsh))
        prefix = app.config.get('SITE_STATIC_PREFIX', '/static/')
        value = '%s%s?v=%s' % (prefix, filename, hsh[:5])
        app._static_hash[filename] = value
        return value

    @app.context_processor
    def register_context():
        return dict(
            static_url=static_url,
            ...
        )
```

Then use `static_url("js/a.js")` instead of `url_for("static", filename="js/a.js")` in you jinja template.